# Getting Distinct rows with LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, distinct

i currently have mutliple records for each "FileStreamID" but i only want to get one distinct one based on the latest "request date"

here is what i have now:

```
 var resultx = from v in ctx.vEmailSents
                             where v.Lab_ID == 44
                                 && v.UploadDate >= this.BeginDate
                             select new
                             {

                                 FileStreamID = v.FileStream_ID,
                                 UploadDate = v.UploadDate,
                                 RequestDate = v.DateSent,
                                 TypeDesc = v.TypeDesc
                             };
```

and now i get about 33 records (but i should only get 12)

how can i change it to only give me distinct rows on filestream IDs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group your `vEmailSent` objects by `FileStream_ID` and select from each group item with latest date:

```
 var resultx = from v in ctx.vEmailSents
               where v.Lab_ID == 44
                     && v.UploadDate >= this.BeginDate
               group v by v.FileStream_ID into g
               select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateSent)
                       .FirstOrDefault() into lastV
               select new {
                      FileStreamID = lastV.FileStream_ID,
                      UploadDate = lastV.UploadDate,
                      RequestDate = lastV.DateSent,
                      TypeDesc = lastV.TypeDesc                          
               };
```

Comment: thank you!! i think that did it! all hail to the all mighty LINQ god, @lazyberezovsky!

Comment: BTW, the post that was deleted, works if the select new {x ...} contains only the fields to be compared.  Often .Distinct() is the better the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = resultx
    .GroupBy(x => x.FileStreamID)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.RequestDate).First());
```